# Removing root of BST

Tags: python, python-3.x, data-structures, binary-search-tree

I'm trying to remove make a function that deletes any element of the BST. Everything works well except the case when I try to delete the root of the tree (by the root I mean the first element of the list when printing tree pre-order). When I try to delete that element, nothing gets deleted. I'm not sure what causes this issue.

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, value=None):
        self.value = value
        self.left = None
        self.right = None

    def insert(self, value):
        if not self.value:
            self.value = value
            return
        if value < self.value:
            if self.left:
                self.left.insert(value)
                return
            self.left = Node(value)
            return
        if value > self.value:
            if self.right:
                self.right.insert(value)
                return
            self.right = Node(value)

    def pre_order(self, values):
        if self.value is not None:
            values.append(self.value)
        if self.left is not None:
            self.left.pre_order(values)
        if self.right is not None:
            self.right.pre_order(values)
        return values

    def delete(self, value):
        if self == None:
            return self
        if value < self.value:
            self.left = self.left.delete(value)
            return self
        if value > self.value:
            self.right = self.right.delete(value)
            return self
        if self.right == None:
            return self.left
        if self.left == None:
            return self.right
        min_larger_node = self.right
        while min_larger_node.left:
            min_larger_node = min_larger_node.left
        self.value = min_larger_node.val
        self.right = self.right.delete(min_larger_node.value)
        return self

l = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
BST = Node()
for i in l:
    BST.insert(i)

before_deleting = []
print(BST.pre_order(before_deleting))

BST.delete(1)

after_deleting = []
print(BST.pre_order(after_deleting))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> except the case when I try to delete the root of the tree

This is because the root node is represented by your `BST` variable, and nothing gets assigned to that variable when you call `delete`.

There are more problems though:

- If you call the `delete` method with a value that is not found in the tree, an exception will occur, because a call to `self.left.delete(value)` will be made at a moment that `self.left` is `None`. You can avoid this by calling the method as if it were a static method: `Node.delete(self.left, value)`.
- When you call `delete` on a node that has two children, an error occurs on `self.value = min_larger_node.val`. There is no `val` attribute. It should be `value`.
- If the value 0 is added to the tree with `insert(0)`, it might get overwritten. For instance, if the input is `[2, 0, 1]`, the tree will end up with only 2 and 1. This is because of a peculiar handling with a `not self.value` condition (see below).
- Even if you assign the result of `BST.delete()` back to the `BST` name, you'll eventually get an empty tree where `BST` is `None`, and then calling any method on `BST` (like `BST.pre_order()`) will fail with an error.
- With the initialisation of the tree you have worked around the previous issue by adding a dummy node with value `None`, which is also the reason why you have this `not self.value` condition in your code -- but it breaks the correct functioning of your tree. You should not have such dummy node, but regard an empty tree as a tree **without** nodes, not with a dummy node. Instead, create a second class that will deal with the `None` value you might have for the root.
- Not a major problem, but it is not nice that one has to pass a list as argument to `pre_order`. It would be better if that method would create the list itself and return it. It is also more pythonic to use a generator for producing the values according to a pre order traversal.

Here is how that would work:

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, value):  # No special None value (removed default)
        self.value = value
        self.left = None
        self.right = None

    def insert(self, value):
        # No special condition for detecting dummy nodes here.
        if not self:
            return Node(value)
        if value < self.value:
            self.left = Node.insert(self.left, value)
        elif value > self.value:
            self.right = Node.insert(self.right, value)
        return self

    def delete(self, value):
        if not self:
            return self
        if value < self.value:
            self.left = Node.delete(self.left, value)  # Safe for when None
            return self
        if value > self.value:
            self.right = Node.delete(self.right, value)
            return self
        if not self.right:
            return self.left
        if not self.left:
            return self.right
        min_larger_node = self.right
        while min_larger_node.left:
            min_larger_node = min_larger_node.left
        self.value = min_larger_node.value
        self.right = self.right.delete(min_larger_node.value)
        return self

    def pre_order(self):  # generator
        if self:
            yield from Node.pre_order(self.left)
            yield from Node.pre_order(self.right)
            yield self.value

class BST:  # Container class for managing the root
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = None  # An empty tree has no nodes: no dummies!

    def insert(self, value):
        self.root = Node.insert(self.root, value)    

    def delete(self, value):
        self.root = Node.delete(self.root, value)
    
    def pre_order(self):  # generator
        return Node.pre_order(self.root)


lst = [4, 2, 6, 1, 3, 5, 7]
tree = BST()
for value in lst:
    tree.insert(value)

tree.delete(4)

print(*tree.pre_order())  # 1 3 2 7 6 5
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed reply, that's really helpful - everything works now