# BST delete method not functioning well

Tags: python, binary, binary-search-tree

So i have been haviong a hard time with binary search tree, and now even AI arent helping with this specific problem which i guess is an issue of a logic missed. The delete method isnt working as it should and i need help. The tree.delete(2) should delete 2 and 2 shoulndt be printed at the end which it still print 2 anyways. I will love any help rendered.

```
class BstNode:
    def __init__(self, val=None) :
        self.val = val
        self.left = None
        self.right = None

    def insert(self, val):
        if   self.val == None:
            self.val = val
        elif self.val == val:
            print("Duplicate Value") 
            return
        elif val > self.val:
            if self.right == None:
                self.right = BstNode(val)
            else:
                self.right.insert(val)
        elif val < self.val:
            if self.left == None:
                self.left = BstNode(val)
            else:
                self.left.insert(val)

        # the init_call values are for the print just to debug, has no uses after this to print full list after all recursive call
      
    def preorder(self, visited=None, init_call=True):
        if visited is None:
            visited = []
        visited.append(self.val)
        if self.left:
            self.left.preorder(visited, False)
        if self.right:
            self.right.preorder(visited, False)
        if init_call:  # Check if this is the initial call to the function
            print(visited)
        return visited

    def postorder(self, visited=None, init_call=True):
        if visited is None:
            visited = []
        if self.left:
            self.left.postorder(visited, False)
        if self.right:
            self.right.postorder(visited, False)
        visited.append(self.val)
        if init_call:  # Check if this is the initial call to the function
            print(visited)
        return visited

    # in order from lowest to highest
    def inorder(self, visited=None, init_call=True):
        if visited is None:
            visited = []
        if self.left:
            self.left.inorder(visited, False)
        visited.append(self.val)
        if self.right:
            self.right.inorder(visited, False)
        if init_call:  # Check if this is the initial call to the function
            print(visited)
        return visited
    
        
    def print(self):
        if self.left:
            self.left.print()
        if self.val !=None:
            print(self.val)
        if self.right:
            self.right.print()
    def get_min(self):
        if self.left is None:
            print(self.val)
            return self.val
        return self.left.get_min()
    def get_max(self):
        if self.right is None:
            print (self.val)
            return self.val
        return self.right.get_max()
    def exist(self, val):
        if self.val == val:
            return True
        if self.right and val > self.val:
            return self.right.exist(val)
        elif self.left and val < self.val:
            return self.left.exist(val)
        return False
    def height(self):
        if self.val is None:
            return 0
        left_height = 0
        right_height = 0
        if self.left:
           left_height= self.left.height()
        if self.right:
           right_height= self.right.height()
        return 1 + max(left_height, right_height)
    
    def delete(self, val):
        if self.val is None:
            return self
        elif val < self.val:
            if self.left:
                self.left = self.left.delete(val)
        elif val > self.val:
            if self.right:
                self.right = self.right.delete(val)
        else:
            
            
            if self.right is None:
                temp = self.left
                del self 
                return temp
            elif self.left is None:   
                temp =  self.right
                del self 
                return temp
            else:
                temp = self.right.findMin()
                self.val = temp.val
                self.right = self.right.delete(temp.val)
            
        return self


         
       
    def findMin(self):
        current = self
        while current.left is not None:
            current = current.left
        return current




def fill_tree(tree, num_range = 10, max_int = 100):
    from random import randint
    tree.insert(35)
    for _ in range( num_range):
        
        cur_element = randint(0, max_int)
        tree.insert(cur_element)
    return tree


tree = BstNode()
tree.insert(2)
tree.insert(5)
tree.insert(7)
tree.insert(10)
tree.insert(20)
tree.insert(35)
print("_________PRINT________________")
tree.print()
print("_________PREORDER________________")
tree.preorder()
print("_________POSTORDER________________")
tree.postorder()
print("_________INORDER________________")
tree.inorder()
print("_________GETMIN________________")
tree.get_min()
print("_________GETMAX________________")
tree.get_max()
print("_________EXISIT________________")
print(tree.exist(35))
print("_________HEIGHT________________")
print(tree.height())
tree.delete(2)
tree.delete(5)
tree.delete(7)
tree.delete(10)
tree.delete(20)
tree.delete(35)
print("_________PRINT________________")
tree.print()
```

After 2-3 days i managed to understand and compile this code

the print shhould print nothing at the end, but still prints two which indicate the print not working on two, since 2 is the lowest it should be at the end of the left side. I will appreciate all help rendered.

Comment: Not your question, but at first glance you seem to consider a tree the same as a node, giving the uncomfortable situation where you must have a node, even if the tree is empty, giving the value `None` some magic meaning to say that although this is a node, it is not really a node. Bad design. This leads to cases where `.exists(None)` is True at first, but when you add a value to the tree it returns False. Just one of the many problems. Use two classes.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that when your `delete` function, on its first invocation, detects that the (root) node has the value to delete (i.e. 2), it returns a child node reference, but that returned reference is going "nowhere": your main program is not looking at what `delete` returns, and just expects that the job is done. Furthermore, `del self` is not doing anything useful, at least not to the tree. That just unbinds a name. And so nothing changes -- no node is deleted.

A quick fix is to replace `del self` with `self.val = None` at both places where you have it. This at least "clears" the node, giving it a "zombie" status. If then it happens to be the root node, it will be considered deleted, even though `tree` will still be a reference to *that* node.

Although this fixes your immediate issue, it is a bad design choice to use the same class to represent the tree and a node. The consequence is that you need to treat `None` as a magic value that kind of "invalidates" the node, as you don't have a clean way to represent an *empty* tree -- your approach necessitates that there is always at least one node, as that is your reference to the tree. So to represent an empty tree you create a "zombie" node with the value `None`. This leads to lots of problems, leading to code that needs to always check whether the current node is maybe such a "zombie" node. Your code is not always doing that, and so there are still bugs there (for instance in `exists`).

I would however advise to create a second class, `Bst`, with an attribute `root`, which will either be `None` (when the tree is empty), or the reference to the root node (an instance of `BstNode`). Then add all the methods you need to *that* class -- they can forward such calls to `BstNode` if relevant. But the important advantage is now that you can truly represent an empty tree, and don't need code to detect and manage "zombie" nodes. It will also help to write elegant code for your methods, which on `Bst` can be very concise, as they can rely on the methods with the same name on the `BstNode` class.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75846308/5459839) is an answer of mine that proposes that design, with code.

Comment: Thanks so much, I will be refactoring my code to use a separate node. If I didn't get it right will check  your example.